# Mysql left join limit

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to limit the last left join to only 1 result

```
$query="SELECT a.*, cc.name AS category, ee.ezcity AS proploc
       , dd.name AS statename, bb.name AS countryname
       , u.logo_image AS logo_image, u.mid AS mid
       , u.dealer_name AS dealer_name, u.dealer_company AS dealer_company
       , u.dealer_phone AS dealer_phone, u.dealer_mobile AS dealer_mobile
       , u.published AS dealerpublished, sp.tenant AS tenant
       , sp.spacenum AS spacenum, sp.sf AS sf, sp.image AS tenantimage
       , u.dealer_type AS dealer_type 
     FROM #__ezrealty as a"
    . "\n LEFT JOIN #__ezrealty_catg AS cc ON cc.id = a.cid"
    . "\n LEFT JOIN #__ezrealty_locality AS ee ON ee.id = a.locid"
    . "\n LEFT JOIN #__ezrealty_state AS dd ON dd.id = a.stid"
    . "\n LEFT JOIN #__ezrealty_country AS bb ON bb.id = a.cnid"
    . "\n LEFT JOIN #__ezrealty_profile AS u ON u.mid = a.owner"
    . "\n LEFT JOIN #__ezrealty_siteplan AS sp ON sp.listing_id = a.id "
    . "\n WHERE $extrastring AND a.published = '1' $vacant 
          AND cc.access <= $my->gid $wheres "
    . $order.' LIMIT '.$pageNav->limitstart.', '.$pageNav->limit;
```

I have tried :

```
. "\n  LEFT JOIN (SELECT listing_id FROM #__ezrealty_siteplan LIMIT 1) sp 
         ON sp.listing_id = a.id"
```

Comment: It looks like you select a `listing_id` from ezrealty_siteplan at random? How do you know that's going to match with `a.id`? Should you not change `(SELECT listing_id FROM #__ezrealty_siteplan LIMIT 1)` to `(SELECT listing_id FROM #__ezrealty_siteplan WHERE listing_id = .... LIMIT 1)`

Comment: Very confused as to what you are trying to do. If you change your `LEFT JOIN`'s to `INNER JOIN`'s does that help?

Comment: I solved it with this:
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM #__ezrealty_siteplan GROUP BY listing_id)AS sp ON sp.listing_id = a.id 

The problem was each realty listing was one listing itself (an entire shopping center) and the listing needed to have sub listings that contained the leased and available spaces in the shopping center. When a user searched, it would show the same shopping center 5x if the shopping center had 5 available spaces.

Comment: next time try listing that you got 5 identical rows, then I would have known to tell you to change the `select a.*....` into `select distinct a.*....` good to know you got your stuff solved though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your result look like it contains more than 1 because the results are not GROUP BY any column.

Comment: GROUP BY is used with aggregates.  Coincidentally, it will eliminate duplicates, but that is far from being what it is designed for.  If a query needs a GROUP BY to eliminate duplicates, it usually means the query is mis-designed. A DISTINCT qualifier on the SELECT clause is simpler and more portable than a GROUP BY clause that includes only some of the column names from the SELECT clause, which MySQL allows but other DBMS do not.

Comment: Not a mysql expert in any way but I couldnt find much help, and I was able to piece this together and it appears to work:

LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM #__ezrealty_siteplan GROUP BY listing_id)AS sp ON sp.listing_id = a.id 

I will select your answer because it pointed me in a direction that crudely accomplished what I need (If I understand right, there should be a better way to do this)